# How do I update scores in table without using a ranking function

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Table name is: result

```
ID  Name   score    position
1   John    40        0
2.  Ali     79        0
3   Ben     50        0
4   Joe     79        0
```

How can I update table result to give me the table below without using rank() as it does not support by server. Pls someone should help me with the MySQL code That breaks ties just as in table below.

```
ID  Name  score   position
1   John   40        4
2.  Ali    79        1
3   Ben    50        3
4   Joe    79        1
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use a ranking function?

Answer (score 1):

In `MySQL` prior to version 8 try using the multiple table update syntax:

```
UPDATE scores t
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT t1.id, COUNT(*) + 1 AS new_position
    FROM scores t1
    JOIN scores t2 ON t1.score < t2.score 
    GROUP BY t1.id
  ) agg ON t.id = agg.id
SET t.position = COALESCE(agg.new_position, 1)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=dc287edf49bc889b1031e57d3905f3ca)

Comment: A left join on an update is a strange thing

Comment: @Strawberry, otherwise, there will be a zero position. Replace the left join in the fiddle with an inner join and you will see.

Comment: Sure, but two updates might be faster; the first setting all 0 values to 1, and then running yours with an inner join.

Answer (score 0):

You can use correlated sub-query as follows:

```
update your_table t
  set t.position = (select count(*) + 1 from your_table tt
                     where tt.score > t.score)
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to skin this particular animal. How about...

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,Name   VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL 
,score  INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'John',40),
(2,'Ali',79),
(3,'Ben',50),
(4,'Joe',79);
  
  SELECT id
       , name
       , score
       , FIND_IN_SET(score, scores) rank
    FROM my_table
   CROSS 
    JOIN 
       ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(score ORDER BY score DESC) scores
           FROM my_table
       ) scores
       
+----+------+-------+------+
| id | name | score | rank |
+----+------+-------+------+
|  1 | John |    40 |    4 |
|  2 | Ali  |    79 |    1 |
|  3 | Ben  |    50 |    3 |
|  4 | Joe  |    79 |    1 |
+----+------+-------+------+
```

I've not provided an UPDATE, because you wouldn't normally store derived data.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate